# Cant use getline when writing to a file?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a string set by the cin command to a file. I have it working, but it is not writing all of the string; just everything ebfore the first white space. So someone suggested I use:

```
Write_Test << getline( Text , cin );
```

To make it accept white spaces, but as the title says I cant use getline?

All code:

```
string Text;
        cout << "Write something: ";
        cin >> Text;
        if (Text != "")
        {           
            ifstream Write_Test("Write_Test.txt");//Creating the file       
            //Write_Test << Text;       //Write a message to the file.
            Write_Test << getline( Text , cin );
            Write_Test.close();                 //Close the stream, meaning the file will be saved.     
            cout << "Done!";
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It shouldn't.  But he really shouldn't be using a function without reading its specifications.

Comment: As it's name suggests you use `getline` to read, not to write. Your error is not that you are writing wrongly, but that you are reading wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably meant to write

```
std::getline(std::cin, Text)
```

This expression take an `std::istream&` and returns this `std::istream&`. Assuming you got the arguments of `getline()` right, the expression

```
out << std::getline(std::cin, Text)
```

actually write the stream state of `std::cin` to `out`. This may be what you wanted but my guess is that you actually meant to use

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, Text)) {
    WriteTest << Text;
}
```

This should write a line of text read from `std::cin` to `WriteTest`.

A complete program would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out("WriteTest.txt");
    if (!out) {
        std::cout << "Error: failed to open output file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::string text;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, text)) {
        out << text << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error: failed to read a line\n";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that he should use ofstream instead of ifstream. Update

Comment: Right ok thankyou, but what is happening now is that it is writing everything after the first white space?

Comment: @user2799788 `getline(Text, cin)` shouldn't even compile...  `WriteTest << getline(cin, Text)` would first read a line from cin into Text, then write status bits from cin into WriteTest.  By all means, get `getline()` onto a separate line and don't "chain" it until you have all this worked out.

Comment: @user2799788: If there isn't anything preceding the use of `std::getline(std::cin, Text)` (and if you used an `std::ofstream` instead of an `std::ifstream` as khajvah pointed out), it should print the first line (without a trailing newline; to add that add `'\n'`). If it doesn't, please post the [CCSSE](http://ccsse.org/) showing the actual code.

Comment: Ok, I dont really understand how to do this; I think I may be trying to run before I can walk with c++. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2799788: Which part do you have problems with? Just use the code in posted to replace your code and add the definition of an `std::ifstream` named `WriteTest`. I'll turn my snippet into a complete program...